# ZenHub API requests using Javascript

Tags: javascript, git, api, github-issues, zenhub

I am currently using ZenHub enterprise and want to know how can I get GitHub issues with Zenhub details in there? I am already able to fetch the issues using git API, however that doesn't have parameters like the release, pipeline, epics and estimate. How do I do that using javascript? Thanks